# Invoking a singleton class in a abstract factory method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have a class with abstract factory method as follows:

```
 public abstract class OpClass
    {
        public abstract IHou OperationInvoke(string opClass);
    }

    public class FactoryClass : OpClass
    {
        public override IHou OperationInvoke(string opClass)
        {
            if(opClass == "T")
            {
                //new Treasure();
            }

        }
    }
```

and the concrete "Treasure" class goes like this:

```
 public interface IHou
    {
        void Operation(Player p, List<Player> lstPlayers);
    }

public sealed class Treasure : IHou
    {
        private static Treasure instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        Treasure()
        {

        }

        public static Treasure Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Treasure();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Operation(Player p, List<Player> lstPlayers)
        {
            p.Points = p.Points + 200;

        }
    }
```

In my main Method I am trying to call it as:

```
Main()
{
    Player p = //Populate from db;
    List<Player> players = //populate from db 
    OpClass c = new FactoryClass();
    IHou output = c.OperationInvoke("T");
    output.Operation(p, players);
}
```

But the thing I need a single instance of **"Treasure"** class so I had the idea of changing the normal **"Treasure"** class to a singleton class.

So in this scenario how do I create a single instance of Treasure class and also preserve facory pattern? And if it's not possible to implement whats the best solution if the number of concrete classes get added like Treasure , House , Blocks etc.?

**Edit** : Is it not appropriate to use factory pattern here , as my understanding was if we have many classes with common behaviours like in this Treasure , and say one more class "**House**" gets added which calculates points in a different way , I will allow the factory to decide to invoke which one to instantiate.

Comment: Note you should _also_ check outside the lock if `instance` is null, else you will have to lock every time, even when you have an instance, which means threads will have to fight for a lock. One check outside, one check inside.

Comment: Can you use DI-container? Things like this usually are DI-container responsibility. Any DI-container can manage this out-of-box.

Comment: You dont need factory pattern. factory pattern is used when number of parameters required to initialize an instance is large and initialization is not straightforward or when you need some additional logic in between the initialization and using the instance. your `Treasure` doesnt even take a single parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of Flyweight pattern for this, in this pattern you will store instance in cache or dictionary and return it from the factory

with the help of generics based implementation of factory as below you dont need to add more cases , it will create class based on Template type T. you can visit article link below have same king of implemenration.

```
public class FlyWeidhtFactory
{
    Dictionary<string,IHou> dic = new Dictionary<string,IHou>();

    public IHou OperationInvoke<T>(string opClass)  where T: IHou 
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        string fullname = type.FullName;
        if(!dic.Contains(fullname)
        {
           Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
           dic[fullname] = (T)obj;  
           //no need of more cases 
        }
        return dic[opClass]; 
    }
}
```

pattern ensure that you are going to create many objects, and by above implementation you are sure that only one instance of you class will get created. no need to go for singleton pattern.

Make your concrete class `internal sealed`, so it will not be visible outside you assembly.

Above is just suggestion based on your question.

Articles for factory and flyweight :

- [Flyweight Design Pattern](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/09/flyweight-design-pattern.html)
- [Factory Design Pattern With Generics](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=1194836729866470946#editor/target=post;postID=2009371472569706985;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname)

Answer (score 0):

Just return the singleton instance in the factory.

Your factory has the responsibility of knowing how to 'make'. In the case of Treasure, there is only one instance, so the Factory just returns that.

The fact that you are returning shared or unshared instances based on a key makes your code similar to flyweight. If no other code needs to create Treasure outside the factory, then you do not need a Singleton. You can force the classes to be instantiated via the factory by making them nested classes of the factory.

So make Treasure a nested class of the factory with a private constructor. Or make it a private nested class and use the factory method to return an abstract base.